# How to Resolve 'Blocked by robots.txt' Error Despite 'User-agent: * Allow: /' Directive?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I manage multiple custom-made websites hosted on the same server and with the same configuration, including sharing a Google Search Console account. Despite all sites utilizing the same robots.txt file, the most recently added website fails to index, displaying the error message "Page cannot be indexed: Blocked by robots.txt" when inspected using the Google Search Console URL inspection tool.

**The robots.txt content:**

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

**The error I get:**
[image]

I am seeking information from others who may have experienced this issue and whether it could potentially be attributed to a cache problem on Google's end as clicking the retest URL results in the same error. It is worth noting that the domain had a previous website prior to the implementation of the new site, and all other websites on the server return valid results without issue. Additionally, various robots.txt checkers have confirmed that the site is not blocked, indicating that the error message is unique to Google's tool.

Comment: How long has it been since you added this website?

Comment: Why are you using `Allow: /` rather than the standard `Disallow:` (disallow nothing) as specified by the offical robots.txt spec at  https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html under the heading "To allow all robots complete access"

Comment: Is that the entirety of your robots.txt file? Aside from it not being a standard way of allowing all crawlers as Stephen mentioned, I don't see any reason those directives should cause googlebot to be blocked.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller
It's been more than 48 hours since I've added it.
I've always used that, and even after I've changed it to "Disallow:" the error still persists

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister
Yes that the entirety of the robots.txt file

Comment: Google caches robots.txt for 24 hours.  However it can take weeks for errors in Google Search Console to clear.  You probably just need to give it that amount of time.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for your assistance in resolving the issue with my robots.txt file. The answer provided below by GeoffAtkins was instrumental in helping me to understand that the error was caused by cached data. I am now waiting patiently for the robots.txt file to update. I sincerely appreciate your contribution in helping me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Google Search Console does indeed cache robots.txt files. I have personal experience of it doing this.

However, Google allows you to see exactly how they view your robots.txt file and whether they are caching an out of date version, using their robots.txt tester tool (part of Google Search Console).

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Be aware, this does not work for domain properties, so if your website is already added as a domain property, you'll have to add it as a standard property as well.

You can trigger Google to fetch the live version of the file, and test variations of your rules, and directly establish if Google considers itself blocked from any URLs within your property.

Hitting the submit button beneath the tester's textarea (where you can edit the robots.txt rules) brings up this dialogue, allowing you to require Google update their cached robots.txt.
[image: GSC Robots.txt tester modal with instructions to request recaching of robots.txt file]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your information. I appreciate your insight on the caching solution as it appears to be the most viable option.

I have attempted to add a property to my account, but the tool displays a screen with the message "Don't see your property? You can add it to your account." When I attempt to add a property, I am redirected to a page where I am only able to view my existing properties or verify them. Despite watching instructional videos, I have not been able to resolve this issue and have decided to discontinue using the tool.

Comment: Once in Google Search Console, click the hamburger (three horizontal lines) icon in the top left, then the select property drop down, then Add Property. Enter your website address as a "URL prefix" property (use the URL as you want it to appear and it should then be available through the robots.txt tester.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution to an issue that I have been grappling with for quite some time. With your assistance, I am now able to use the tester effectively. However, I must note that the approach taken by Google is somewhat cryptic, and it would be beneficial for them to provide clearer guidance on this matter. It appears that the tester is utilizing cached data, which may explain the error I encountered. I am curious if there are any methods to force the use of updated data, or if I should simply wait for Google to refresh its cache before conducting further tests?

Comment: You can use the URL inspection tool and perform a "live" test there that will force it test the file again by downloading it.  I don't think it will cause a re-download of robots.txt though.

Comment: You can certainly see the last time Google accessed your robots.txt file. If you hit the submit button below the text area (even without changing anything), Google gives you the option to ask them to update what they have cached. I do heartily agree that Google's UX is awful.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I want to clarify that prior to posting the question, I had already attempted to resolve the issue by using the URL Inspection tool in Google Search Console. Despite my best efforts, I was unable to resolve the issue as the Live Test within the URL Inspection tool continued to display a "blocked" notification every time I retested the URL. This is what prompted me to seek assistance on the matter

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I I have now successfully updated my robots.txt file by clicking the "Submit" button. The Live Test is now showing that everything is green and works as intended. I was not aware of this feature before and it was really helpful. Thank you once again for guiding me through the complexities of the search console. Your answers have been instrumental in helping me resolve this issue and I would have been lost without your assistance.

Comment: Glad to help. GSC is a bit of a nightmare for the unprepared.